# webapi won't deserialize string array using $.param

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a ASP.NET WebAPI method and pass it a serialized JavaScript object over a GET request similar to a `$.ajax` POST request. It is working fine except for when the JavaScript object has a null value for Networks, then it sends it in the URL like `/api/airings/get-airings?networks=` and the server is showing the string[] as having a single item with a value of null! If I remove the `network=` it shows up as null on the server as I would expect.

So, it appears that people requested tickets in jQuery regarding this behavior, but I want to know what I can do without using a plugin or rewriting the $.param logic or messing with WebAPI ModelBinder.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8653

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1814

```
public class ApiGetAiringsRequest
{
    public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFinish { get; set; }
    public string[] Networks { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage GetAirings([FromUri] ApiGetAiringsRequest request )
    ...

document.location.href = "/api/airings/get-airings?" + $.param(request);
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please log an issue over here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: hopefully it will be fixed in the next release and looking forward to the attribute routing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to work around this issue I changed the string array to a simple string, and do a .split on it.

```
var serialize = function(obj)
{
    var str = [];

    for (var p in obj)
    {
        if (obj[p])
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }

    return str.join("&");
};

$.get('/api/airings/get-airings?' + serialize(request));
```

C#

```
var networks = (request.Networks??"").Split(',');
```